# WTForms + Multiple Fields & Appending a Span

Tags: wtforms, flask-wtforms

Using WTForms, I want to repeat this block throughout my form:

```
<div class="form-group input-group">
            <select name="multiple[]" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Default select</option>
                <option value="">Option 1</option>
                <option value="">Option 2</option>
            </select>

            <input type="text" name="multiple[]" class="form-control">
            <span class="input-group-btn"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-add">+</button></span>
</div>
```

1. Am I correct to use the [wtforms.fields.FieldList](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.2/fields.html#wtforms.fields.FieldList) enclosure for multiple fields (with the same name attribute)?
2. How do I append the `span` element at the end?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue using another form sub-class.

forms.py (WTForms):

```
class SubForm(Form):
    key = SelectField("Type: ", coerce=int, choices=[(0, "Default select"), (1, "Option 1"), (2, "Option 2")], default=0)
    value = StringField()


class ParentForm(Form):
    ...
    multiple = FormField(SubForm, label="Multiple: ")
    submit = SubmitField("Submit")
```

HTML Template (Jinja):

```
{{ form.multiple.label }}
<div class="form-group input-group">
    {% for field in form.multiple %}
        {{ field(class='form-control') }}
    {% endfor %}
    <span class="input-group-btn"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-add">+</button></span>
</div>
```